# Jenkins 192.168.0.155:8080 ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: jenkins

I set jenkins on my mac and I can enter jenkins by localhost:8080 but not 192.168.0.155:8080.
This is my url setting
[image]

it works on localhost:8080 but not 192.xxx...
it says ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

I found when I go to manage Jenkins it shows red information about my
reverse proxy issue. I don't know what is reverse proxy and how to fix it.

Comment: Probably your firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: my firewall is closing.